# Copied const object in lambda closure not mutable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to capture a const object via copy in a (mutable) lambda. My compiler however complains, that the captured object is const.

Should it not be possible to copy the object as non-const?

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(){}
    void Func(){}
};

int main()
{
    const Foo foo;
    [foo]() mutable { foo.Func(); };
}
```

Compiling with g++ 4.7.2:

```
testcase.cpp: In lambda function:
testcase.cpp:10:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Func() const’
testcase.cpp:10:29: note: candidate is:
testcase.cpp:4:7: note: void Foo::Func() <near match>
testcase.cpp:4:7: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const Foo*’ to ‘Foo*’
```

Compiling with clang++ 3.1:

```
testcase.cpp:10:20: error: member function 'Func' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Foo', but function is not marked const
    std::async([foo]() mutable { foo.Func(); });
```

The Standard document (or rather the draft...) defines in 5.1.2.14 that "The type [...] is the type of the corresponding captured entity", so I guess that would include the cv-specifiers.
It does not seem intuitive though.

Comment: You could explicitly copy inside your lambda body but I guess that's not what you're looking for. You could of course take r-value reference as the parameter given it's C++11.

Comment: @chill This is the question : why the copied foo object inside lambda is const?

Comment: @z33ky, you quoted standard (**The type [...] is the type of the corresponding captured entity**), so why do you expect, that the copy will not preserve const, which should be considered as a part of the type?

Comment: @CashCow The `Foo` in the actual code I want this is is not movable.

Comment: @Stan The standard is not well known to me, so I was not sure if the cv-specifiers are considered part of the type as mentioned. I expect them to not preserve the specifiers because it is a copy, but I would just as well understand if they were kept. In this case I would be wondering how I could get a non-const copy into the closure.

Comment: Yeah my earlier comment was silly about r-value references. However the explicit copy in the body is still valid.

Answer (score 8):

First, the type of a lambda expression, which has capture, is a class type (5.1.2 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda] #3)

That type has an `operator()` which is by default `const`, unless `mutable` is used in the lambda expression ([expr.prim.lambda] #5)

Next, for each entity captured as copy, a unnamed member is declared in the closure type. [expr.prim.lambda] #14]

If you explicitly build the (mostly) equivalent of the capture type, everything will naturally follow from the usual semantics for classes, const-qualified types and const qualified member functions.

Example:

```
struct S
{
  void f();
  void fc() const;
};

void g()
{
  S s0;

  // [s0] ()  { s0.f(); }; // error, operator() is const
  [s0] () { s0.fc(); };    // OK, operator() is const, S::fc is const

  [s0] () mutable { s0.f(); };
  [s0] () mutable { s0.fc(); };

  const S s1;

  // [s1] ()  { s1.f(); }; // error, s1 is const, no matter if operator() is const
  [s1] ()  { s1.fc(); };

  // [s1] () mutable { s1.f(); }; // error, s1 is const, no matter if operator() is const
  [s1] () mutable { s1.fc(); };
}
```

I guess the confusion stems from the fact that `mutable` in the lambda-declarator concerns the `const`-ness of the `operator()`, not the `mutable`-ility of the data members of the closure type. It would be more natural to use `const`, as with member functions, but I guess the standards committee wanted `const` to be the default.

Comment: Well, I figured out what the `mutable` keyword does for the lambda. If the members of the closure would be non-`const`, then I would need the `mutable`-specifier on the lambda to access the non-`const` function. I was just wondering if there was a way to copy the `const` variables as non-`const` into the closure.

Comment: @z33ky, capture it implicitly, copy it explicitly :) `[&]() mutable { Foo f(foo); f.Func(); };`

Comment: I'm returning the lambda from a function, so that captured reference would be invalidated. I guess I'll have to construct a Funktor myself or rely on `const_cast`. Or live with one unnecessary copy-ctor call.

Comment: @chill `auto f = foo; [f] { f.Func(); };` is closer to the intended semantics.

Answer (score 1):

This will work under C++14, not a solution for C++11.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(){}
    void Func(){}
};

int main()
{
    const Foo foo;
    [foo = foo]() mutable { foo.Func(); };
}
```

But I don't really understand why `[foo]` keeps the const but `[foo = foo]` not.

Comment: OP is limited to C++11, but this is indeed the way to go in C++14 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround:

```
  struct Foo
  {
      Foo(){}
      void Func(){}
  };

  int main()
  {
      const Foo foo;
      {
          Foo& fooo= const_cast<Foo&>(foo);
          [fooo]() mutable { fooo.Func(); };
      }
  }
```

This solution has safety problems (accidental modification of const object through non-const reference is possible), but additional copying is avoided.

Comment: If this is necessary, it means `Func()` should have been marked `const`. If so, this is a separate issue from the lambda, so this answer, while true, isn't really a solution. (One would either fix `Func()` to be cv-qualified, or if modification is not possible provide a free-function `void Func_unsafe(const Foo& f) { const_cast<Foo&>(f).Func(); }` and use that in the lambda; regardless, the lambda has no business with the issue.)

Comment: GManNickG: If Func really modifies the object and is marked const, it is global security issue for the whole program, whenever the const Foo appears. By introducing const-casted reference  (instead of making Func const), I localized this issue inside the block around the lambda, where the const-casted refernce resides. As const-casted fooo is used only for making a copy,the only restriction is that Foo's copy ctor shouldn't modify the object (what is the usual case). Not perfect, I agree, but it is better than making Func() const globally.

Comment: GManNickG: ... As to void Func_unsafe(), it exposes UB  since it modifies an object that is actually const (i.e. const member of the lambda class)

Comment: The whole premise of my comment was that `Func()` should have been marked const and, of course, could be. That's the only reason for your cast.

Comment: GManNickG: no, the reason for "my cast" is to capture (by value!) const Foo by making its non-const copy inside the lambda class. After that  arbitrary non-const function may safely modify this non-const copy, since the original const object remains unchanged (it is exactly what the OP wants to achive). The only possible vulnerability i can see is that copy constructor (since we remove const qualifier from its argument) can attempt to change original object, but it is unlikely.